# How to use binary search to find a pickle object attribute

Tags: python, object, pickle, binary-search

I am creating a program that works as a database that stores students, as objects. Each object (student) has three attributes: name, grade, and average. I am trying to incorporate a binary search so that the user can search for an average. If the average is found in one of the object's attributes, then the program should display the object. Right now I am trying to get the binary search to work; if I search for an average that is stored in an even-index, then it works, however it doesn't work for any odd-indexes. Does anyone know why this is happening? Also, I am trying to display the object that contains the average that is being searched for, but so far I have only been able to display the index location of the object that contains the searched average. Any help with displaying the object would be appreciated!

My program is as follows:

```
import pickle

class Student():
    def __init__(self,nam,grd,avg):
        self.name = nam
        self.grade = grd
        self.average = avg

    def get_details(self):
        print(self.name, self.grade, self.average)

def unpickle_database(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            try:
                yield pickle.load(f)
            except EOFError:
                break

def display_database():
    print("\nName:               Grade:              Average:            ")
    for student in unpickle_database('student_data.pkl'):
        property_list = [student.name, student.grade, student.average]
        print(''.join([v.ljust(20,' ') for v in property_list]))

def store_averages_in_list():
    students = list(unpickle_database('student_data.pkl'))
    students_average = []
    for student in students:
        students_average.append(int(student.average))
    return students_average

def bin_search(x, type):
    my_list = list(sorted(store_students_in_list(), key=attrgetter(type), reverse=False))
    bottom = 0
    top = len(my_list)-1
    found = False
    location = -1
    while (bottom <= top) and not(found):
        middle = int((bottom + top)/2)

        if (my_list[middle] == x):
            location = middle
            found = True
        elif (my_list[middle] < x):
            bottom = middle + 1
        else:
            top = middle -1
    return location

while True:
    user_input = input()
    if user_input == "Search":
        print(bin_search(int(input("Enter average to search for: ")),'average'))
```

Comment: if `create_item` is a method of the class not an instance you should mark it as such using [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod). If you just want it to be static and take no arguments you can also use [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

Comment: You should first try to get the basics of binary search working on, say, a list of (sorted) integers.  There's **a lot** of extraneous code there that isn't necessary and may complicate things for you.

Comment: The binary search method looks fine to me. If it’s not working then your list is probably not actually sorted correctly.

Comment: [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/bisect.html) is part of the Python standard library.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists

Comment: Of course! I completely forgot that binary search only works on a sorted list! Now I just need to figure out how to make it work with objects.